# calling array in porting C# to PHP

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I'm kinda new to C# and want to port some program from C# to PHP

one thing strange for me is,

```
double[][] rate = { new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                    new double[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
                  };
double[,,] quest = {{{1,2,3,4}, {1,1,2,3}, {2,3,4,5}},
                    {{2,3,4,5}, {1,1,1,1}, {3,3,3,3}}
                   };

for ( int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++ ){
    dummy = rate[i][(int)quest[1, 1, 1] - 3];
}
```

my question is,
why can you call cube-array quest[1,1,1] this way, but then again why call array rate[i][blah] like in PHP?

do they work interchangeably? just a matter of expression , or something more than I know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int[,,]` is a multidimensional array.  It's also called a rectangular array, as it's more like an X-dimensional rectangular block of ints (with X=3 in this case).  Each slice, row, and column of the array has the same size as any other slice/row/column, respectively.

`int[][][]` is an array of arrays of arrays of ints.  It's more treeish.  It's also called a "jagged" array, because each array at a given index can have different lengths.

In many cases, the two can do the same things, but they each have their strengths.  Rectangular arrays have a predictable "shape", and you don't have to be as paranoid about whether `x[a, b, c]` exists if `a`, `b` and `c` are within the bounds you set when you created the array.  You also don't have to worry about creating arrays and subarrays for each level of the array.  On the other hand, jagged arrays can be more flexible when it comes to resizing and expanding one part of the array without doing the whole thing.

As far as analogous structures go, a jagged array is closer to how PHP tends to treat arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is array-of-array and the another is Multidimensional array.
here is the link talk about this [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)